# Add filters dropdown to line plot based on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I have dataframe and want to visualize *in-line plots* that represents in a whole vehicle **segmentation** status in *Active, Registered*, and *Productive*. the status is count from transaction by month.

[small dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbqQK.png) (image example)

In the x axis I want to put the *month* and in the y axis is *Active, Registered,* and *Productive*. and I try by implementing this code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('company.csv')
fig = px.line(df1, x = 'month', y = ['registered', 'active', 'productive'], markers = True)
fig.show()
```

output: [plotly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7qc9.png)

I also want to filter by company in dropdown and value get from dataframe column company, so when I select a determined company that represents their value status (*Active, Registered, Productive*).

How can I make dropdown into plotly or any other way?.

Comment: can you post you dataframe snippet as text instead of image

Answer (score 0):

- have simulated your data frame
- from this I understand that each company is a group of lines.  Have created figure that has all groups
- finally build a dropdown menu that allows you to filter.  This can also be done from the legend

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

c = ["Sircio", "Nippon", "Toshiba", "Budget Group", "Northern Factory", "Cobot Corp"]
df1 = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "company": np.tile(c, 8),
                "month": np.repeat(
                    pd.date_range("1-Feb-21", freq="MS", periods=8), len(c)
                ),
            }
        ),
        pd.DataFrame(
            np.random.randint(1, 8, [len(c) * 8, 3]),
            columns=["active", "registered", "productive"],
        ),
    ],
    axis=1,
)

fig = go.Figure()
for c in df1["company"].unique():
    fig_tmp = px.line(
        df1.loc[df1["company"].eq(c)],
        x="month",
        y=["registered", "active", "productive"],
        markers=True,
    ).update_traces(legendgroup=c, legendgrouptitle_text=c)

    fig.add_traces(fig_tmp.data)

fig.update_layout(fig_tmp.layout)

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": c,
                    "method": "restyle",
                    "args": ["visible", [t.legendgroup == c for t in fig.data]],
                }
                for c in df1["company"].unique()
            ]
        }
    ]
)
```

[image]